# Wpf Binding filteration

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a doubt binding a textbox.he scenario is like this.I hava a dataset say,

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "table";
dt.Columns.Add("mode", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["mode"] = 1;
dr["value"] = 1000;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["mode"] = 2;
dr["value"] = 2000;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
this.DataContext = ds;
```

The window is bound to this dataset.I have textbox in my window and i want to bind it to the row with mode=1, so that i can show that rows value in the text property of my textbox.

How can i apply this binding..?

Any input will be highly helpfull

Answer (score 1):

DataSets are a bit generic to be using for binding in WPF.  Its usually easier to use the [M-V-VM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern where you have models that are INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyObjects that your UI binds against.

I'm not sure if you're talking about **changing what things are bound to** depending on the "mode" or if you just want **to filter** on "mode."

**In the first case**, you'd have to use a DataTrigger on a Style in order to change the ContentTemplate that you're using based on the value of your mode field.  This is NOT an easy concept for the beginner or intermediate user.

[This is a decent blog post with instructions on how to accomplish this.](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Different_DataTemplates_for_different_data.aspx)  Again, its pretty confusing and when it doesn't work its sometimes hard to troubleshoot.

**In the second case**, you'd be better served by setting your DataContext to a type that contains multiple DataTables that are pre-filtered.  Filtering isn't a job for the UI, its a job for code.  It might look something like:

```
public class MyDataContext
{
  public DataTable ModeOne {get;set;}
  public DataTable ModeTwo {get;set;}
}
```

or perhaps

```
public class MyDataContext
{
  public Dictionary<int, DataTable> TableByMode {get;set;}
}
```

where you would bind like this

```
<ItemsControl Content="{Binding TableByMode[1]}">
```